# Identical parameterised SQL generates SQL that returns no results

Tags: full-text-search, sql-server-2012

Baffling problem. I am using SQL full text search, and I originally executed queries directly using string.format to create them. Here is an example of a SQL string generated by sql profiler:

`SELECT TOP 100 * FROM CatName WHERE CONTAINS(FullName, '"Spotty" AND "Cat"')`

Works great.

However since I am creating that string by taking user input and putting it in, we have the risk of SQL injection. Therefore I created SQL that parameterises it.

The executed SQL in the profiler is this:

`exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP 100 * FROM CatName WHERE CONTAINS(FullName, ''"@p1" AND "@p2"'')',N'@p1 nvarchar(6),@p2 nvarchar(3)',@p1=N'Spotty',@p2=N'Cat'`

As far as I can see, this is the same. However, the 2nd query returns no results.

I suspect it is something to do with the way the parameters are replaced as full text search queries use double-quotes inside single quotes for each parameter, but I am a complete loss.

I need a way to sanitise the input to prevent SQL injection and this is all I could find on the internet.

Any ideas?

The code with and without parameterisation:

```
string _fullTextSearchQuery = "SELECT TOP {0} * FROM {1} WHERE CONTAINS({2}, '{3}')";

var searchText = @"""" + searchText.Replace(" ", @""" AND """) + @"""";
```

and

```
string[] unorderedWords = searchText.Split(' ');

searchText = "";

int unorderedIndex = 1;
foreach (string word in unorderedWords)
{
    searchText += @"""" + "@p" + unorderedIndex + @""" AND ";
    parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("p" + unorderedIndex, word));
    unorderedIndex++;
}

searchText = searchText.Substring(0, searchText.Length - 5);
```

either way followed by this to create the final string:

```
string textSearchQuery = string.Format(
    _fullTextSearchQuery,
    top,
    tableName,
    columnName,
    searchText);
```

`return catContext.SqlQuery<T>(textSearchQuery, parameters.ToArray());`

Because it's a bit of a mess, here is exactly the string as it is generated before it is executed:

non parameterised:

`"SELECT TOP 100 * FROM CatName WHERE CONTAINS(FullName, '\"Spotty\" AND \"Cat\"')"`

parameterised:

`"SELECT TOP 100 * FROM CatName WHERE CONTAINS(FullName, '\"@p1\" AND \"@p2\"')"`

The array of parameters is correct, there are no misc. quotes it is exactly as you'd expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this quite simple, it's important to consider the value being passed into CONTAINS as a single value not as multiple values.

So where I was passing in '"Spotty" AND "Cat"' and assuming this was 2 parameters, in reality the whole string is a single parameter.

So it was a simple case of `"SELECT TOP {0} * FROM {1} WHERE CONTAINS({2}, @P1)";`

where `@P1 = "'\"Spotty\" AND \"Cat\"'"`